# vertical scroll bar in ssrs report is not appearing in ie 11 in non-compatibilty mode

Tags: compatibility, internet-explorer-11, scrollbars, report-viewer2012

I' m using Microsoft report viewer(11.0.0) 2012 version to display a report and in my aspx page, I use the following code. The problem is the report shows vertical scroll bar when in compatible mode, but it disappears in non-compatibility mode. I tried adding overflow property to external div but that scrolls up the report column headers also when scrolling down. I cannot add compatibility meta tag to fix this. Please help. Thanks

```
<div style="height:75%;width:95%;">
    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="DailyReportViewer" AsyncRendering="false" SizeToReportContent="false" BackColor="transparent" DocumentMapWidth="40%" DocumentMapCollapsed="true" InternalBorderColor="Transparent" runat="server">
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>     
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Happened to me as well.
The solution is

```
<body style="margin: 0px; overflow: auto !important;">
```